# *.desktop File Allows Multiple Windows

Tags: firefox, launcher, .desktop

I recently downloaded and installed Firefox Developer Edition, created the appropriate `firefox-dev.desktop` file, and added the shortcut to my Favorites (on Ubuntu 17.10).

Everything seems to be working with one exception: Clicking on the icon in the launcher opens a new window rather than simply focusing the window that is already opened.

Is there a setting in the `firefox-dev.desktop` file that I'm missing or some other bit of Ubuntu dark magic that I need?

Answer (score 0):

`--no-remote` see `firefox -h`

also you could have just clicked Set as default in Preferences [see here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/firefox-reinstall-4175627559/#post5845618)